# Why can't I get anything back when I use Linq to Sql Select?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq-to-sql

Could you please check my code? Why can't I get any values back when I use Linq to Sql?

`BHS_TimeSheet` is my database table in which have some records.

`Model.TimeSheet` is a class I create in the model.

```
Private db As DataFactoryDataContext

Public Sub New()
    db = New DataFactoryDataContext
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal repository As DataFactoryDataContext)
    db = repository
End Sub

Public Function GetTimeSheetByProject(ByVal wbs1 As String, ByVal wbs2 As String, ByVal wbs3 As String) _
    As List(Of Model.TimeSheet) Implements ITimeSheetRepository.GetTimeSheetByProject

    Return (From ts In db.BHS_TimeSheets _
            Where ts.WBS1.Equals(wbs1) And ts.WBS2.Equals(wbs2) And ts.WBS3.Equals(wbs3) _
            Select New Model.TimeSheet(ts.TSBatchNo, ts.Employee, ts.TransDate, ts.WBS1, ts.WBS2, ts.WBS3, ts.LaborCode, _
                                       ts.RegHrs, ts.OvtHrs, ts.SpecialOvtHrs, ts.TransComment, ts.Status, ts.AuthorizedBy, _
                                       ts.RejectReason, ts.ModDate)).ToList

End Function
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Can you trim it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Linq-to-SQL statement

```
   (From ts In db.BHS_TimeSheets 
    Where ts.WBS1.Equals(wbs1) 
      And ts.WBS2.Equals(wbs2) 
      And ts.WBS3.Equals(wbs3) _
```

basically corresponds to this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.BHS_TimeSheets
 WHERE WBS1 = (value for wbs1)
   AND WBS2 = (value for wbs2)
   AND WBS3 = (value for wbs3)
```

Does that SQL query return any values, if you call it with in SQL Server Management Studio using the same parameters for `wbs1, wbs2, wbs3` as you do in your Linq-to-SQL code??

**Update:** okay, so the SQL query does return results - next step: approach the Linq-to-SQL stuff step by step. First, try this - do you get any results??

```
Dim basicQueryResults = (From ts In db.BHS_TimeSheets 
                         Where ts.WBS1.Equals(wbs1) 
                           And ts.WBS2.Equals(wbs2) 
                           And ts.WBS3.Equals(wbs3)
                         ).ToList();
```

Does your resulting list of items have a `.Count > 0` or not??

If not: there must be something wrong with your Linq-to-SQL model then. Have you changed your database and not updated the DBML file?? Can you drop the DBML file and do it again - does it work now? Or do you still have the same results??

Comment: Yes. When I call it with in Sql Server, I get records back.

Comment: @howexg: updated my answer - can you check my questions? Do you get data back??

Comment: Hi,

I fixed the problem, the parameters should take null value, and some table columns shouldn't be empty, and datatype should match with entered.

Thanks!